# App exchange security review - Is it mandatory to follow the SLDS guidelines while designing VF pages?

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-experience, appexchange, lightning-design-system

To create an app that is lightning ready, is it necessary that visualforce pages follow the SLDS guidelines to pass the app exchange security review?

The app that I am working on has mostly custom designs that are different from the lightning look and feel. Is it necessary that SLDS library be used to design the pages or can I use custom CSS?

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to conform with SLDS, although it is strongly recommended. From the [Lightning Ready](https://org62.my.salesforce.com/sfc/p/#000000000062/a/30000000bwUm/Y6To9GKaWAJeRlbaUReGYz4FHR.xW6xLcwahCgIO7DI) slide deck:

> **Do I have to re-style my app in order to be Lightning Ready?**
>
> No, but we do strongly encourage all partners to adopt the Salesforce Lightning Design System to be consistent with the Lightning Experience. This will provide a better experience for our shared customers and reduce cognitive load when switching between apps.

Note however, that being Lightning Ready is a requirement to begin a Security Review:

> Lightning Readiness is a prerequisite for entering the Security Review process.

In other words, all of your Visualforce pages **must** work *correctly* in order to be valid for a Security Review. If it does something it should not, like display errors only in Lightning that do not occur in Classic, or otherwise fail to perform in a comparable manner in both systems, then it will not pass the Security Review.